# 1С и FIREBIRD- передача параметров

Tags: 1с

Как передать параметры в запросе из 1С к `FIREBIRD` (дата между двумя параметрами)

```
Запрос =  "select DISTINCT(NUMBER) from LPREVENTS WHERE LPREVENTS.TIMESTAMP_ BETWEEN  @unixtime AND @unixtime1 ORDER BY ID ";
```

Comment: Сделайте более расширенное описание вашей проблемы. Что именно не получается?